# Is it possible to have a bounded-type variable whose type is not declared in method signature?

Tags: java, android, generics

This question involves Android example but this is more of a pure Java question.

Consider the following classes:

```
interface MyCallback {
    /* ... */
}

class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyCallback {
    /* ... */
    // Note to non-Android guys: Activity is a subclass of Context.
}

class MyAdapter {
    <C extends Context & MyCallback> MyAdapter(C context) {
        /* 
         * For some reason I want to delegate all instanceof-checks and
         * casts to a caller. So at this point I want to be sure
         * context is already of a proper type, hence generic parameter.
         */
    }
}
```

Could you kindly explain how do I generally declare a variable that I can pass to such constructor?

At one point I only have a reference to activity object. I can perform necessary check (whether it implements MyCallback) but I can't pass it as an argument unless I explicitly specify the appropriate type.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    MyAdapter adapter;

    // 1. won't compile:
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());

    // 2. won't compile:
    adapter = new MyAdapter((MyCallback) getActivity());

    // 3. invalid notation:
    adapter = new MyAdapter((Context & MyCallback) getActivity());

    // 4. works but severely limits flexibility:
    adapter = new MyAdapter((MyActivity) getActivity());
}
```

Another option is to do it like this:

```
adapter = createAdater(getActivity())

private <C extends Context & ListToMapCallback>
    MyAdapter createAdapter(Activity activity) {
    // check if activity is castable
    return new MyAdapter((C) activity);
}
```

It's okay albeit a bit ugly. I know it's not a big deal but I was just curious if it's possible to achieve the same result without creating new methods (I can't generify overridden method due to the "same erasure" error).

Thanks!

Comment: you want to enforce that the context you are passing is also a MyCallback ?

Comment: Exactly. And I want a compile-time check for the constructor.

Comment: I don't think it is possible (but I might  be wrong). Why don't you enforce it at runtime ?

Comment: I do enforce it at runtime eventually, but I want it to be enforced by whoever uses the class and not in the class constructor body itself. Simply because it makes for a cleaner code when, in order to use a class, you only have to know a signature and don't need to worry about implementation.

Comment: What does `getActivity()` return? Show the declaration.

Comment: Activity object. `public final Activity getActivity() { /*...*/ }`